# How to use C# List<object> in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to use my C# list in javascript. I tried these, but it doesnt work;

Server side:

```
List<TimeLine> myList= new List<TimeLine>(); 
TimeLine element= new TimeLine ();
element.Name= "abc";
element.About= "ssss";
element.Id = id;

myList.Add(element);

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
model.JSONList= oSerializer.Serialize(myList);

return View(model);
```

Client side:

```
$(function() {
    Draw();
});

function Draw() {
    var tunel = '@Model.JSONList';
    var str = "";
    if (tunel.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tunel.length; i++) {
            str += '<span>'+tunel[i].Name+'</span>'+
            '<span>'+tunel[i].Id+'</span>'+
            '<span>'+tunel[i].About+'</span>';
        }
        $("#myDiv").append(str);
    }
}
```

Can you help me to get the object in list and use it in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Note: I also tried JSON.Parse('@Model.JSONList');
but it doesnt work;
Here is my detailed value. 
`var tunel = JSON.parse('[{&quot;Id&quot;:3,&quot;Tarih&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1425506400000)\/&quot;,&quot;Tip&quot;:2,&quot;Hakkinda&quot;:&quot;- Proje, g&#246;rev, todo d&#246;k&#252;mlerini g&#246;ster.&quot;,&quot;Adı&quot;:&quot;Profil Ekranının Tasarlanması&quot;},{&quot;Id&quot;:26,&quot;Tarih&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1425160800000)\/&quot;,&quot;Tip&quot;:1,&quot;Hakkinda&quot;:&quot;Kişisel işlerin d&#252;zenlenmesi i&#231;in geliştirilen proje.&quot;,&quot;Adı&quot;:&quot;Kişisel Yazılım Asistanı&quot;}]')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to parse your JSON:

```
var tunel = JSON.parse('@Model.JSONList');
```

otherwise you're just doing all your operations on a string.

If you're string is coming out encoded (e.g. `&quot;` instead of `"`) then you can try using `@Html.Raw(Model.JSONList)`:

```
var tunel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.JSONList)');
```

Comment: I tried it also but it doesnt work; Here is my detailed value. var tunel = JSON.parse('[{&quot;Id&quot;:3,&quot;Tarih&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1425506400000)\/&quot;,&quot;Tip&quot;:2,&quot;Hakkinda&quot;:&quot;- Proje, g&#246;rev, todo d&#246;k&#252;mlerini g&#246;ster.&quot;,&quot;Adı&quot;:&quot;Profil Ekranının Tasarlanması&quot;},{&quot;Id&quot;:26,&quot;Tarih&quot;:&quot;\/Date(1425160800000)\/&quot;,&quot;Tip&quot;:1,&quot;Hakkinda&quot;:&quot;Kişisel işlerin d&#252;zenlenmesi i&#231;in geliştirilen proje.&quot;,&quot;Adı&quot;:&quot;Kişisel Yazılım Asistanı&quot;}]')

Comment: @Cracker Please update your question to include all the relevant information.